# GCC: Use -Werror but downgrade a specific error to a warning (in command-line)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-warnings

An example: I'm using `-Wall` `-Werror` and `-Werror`. This means unused `static` functions break the build. Clearly (?) unused functions are Bad, but if I'm working on code and it's in an intermediate state, want to be able to leave unused code in there. I can turn off the error with `-Wno-unused-function`, but then there's a risk that I'll finish what I'm working on, commit the code, and forget to remove the now-unused function.

How can I set all warnings to errors with `-Wall`, but downgrade specific errors to warnings, without disabling them completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-Wno-error=` flags. In the example, the required flag would be `-Wno-error=unused-function`.

PS: There are also pragmas for this purpose: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html (my original question was "How can I do what these pragmas do, but in the command-line flags?" but I worked it out as I was asking it).

Comment: Why don't you want to use the pragmas?

Comment: Just because I'd rather keep this kind of thing in one place i.e. the Makefile. It felt a bit ugly to create a whole header file just to configure compiler diagnostics.